# Object of type Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry is not callable

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I've got an error when trying to use doctrine.

Here is my error:
Object of type Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry is not callable

And my controller:

```
public function index(ManagerRegistry $doctrine): Response
    {
        $articles  = $doctrine()->getRepository(Article::class)->findAll();

      

        
        return $this->render('blog/index.html.twig', [
        'controller_name' => 'BlogController',
        'articles' => $articles,
    ]);
    }
```

Can someone help me ? thanks :)

Comment: Why do you need to use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry? in this function you need Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry. Show more code.

Comment: Use $doctrine->getRepository, remove the parenthesi

Answer (score 0):

This works on Symfony 5.4:

```
use Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;
//...
public function index(ManagerRegistry $doctrine): Response
    {
    $articles  = $doctrine->getRepository(Article::class)->findAll();
    
    return $this->render('blog/index.html.twig', [
       'controller_name' => 'BlogController',
       'articles' => $articles
       ]);
    }
```

You can learn more in [Symfony docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#persisting-objects-to-the-database) and [Doctrine ORM docs](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-persistence/en/3.0/reference/index.html).